# Is it possible to use CSA decryption with FFMPEG?

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, stream, cryptography, vlc

First of all I am sorry if I ask the wrong questions.

I am currently using vlc (libdvbcsa) to encrypt and decrypt live streams and save it to a ts file just by giving

csa-ck= {key}

on server side and

:ts-csa-ck= {key}

on client side. It works as expected.

But I want to use ffmpeg to decrypt ts file and show(I can show normal ts files but not the ones with csa encryption). I tried many input options for ffmpeg with no success and then I realized that ffmpeg has nothing to do with csa and most of them are for aes.

Am I wrong? Can you lead me to a direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use CSA decryption with FFMPEG?

No. I see no mention of CSA encryption/decryption in the source code.

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't either. Can I wait a few days before accepting your answer? Maybe someone will show a way to use it somehow.

Comment: @Sezertt Sure. You can take as long as you want, or choose never to accept it. It's completely up to you.